# react native absolute positioning makes image crop

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have a problem with positioning my image inside a container and that is when I give image `position: absolute` and `top` property image got cropped from the top here's the issue:

[image]

here's my code:

```
<View style={styles.OurTherapistsContainer}>
          <View style={styles.therapistCard}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/img/leong.png')} />
            </View>
          </View>
      </View>

...
therapistCard: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#DFEEFF',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: "absolute",
    top: 30
  }
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using resizeMode in image style like

```
resizeMode:'contain'
```

Comment: Yes thank you but this makes my image too small, no other way?

Comment: Try adding {width: 150, height: 150} in image style and top: 10 like that

Answer (score 0):

set resizeMode to **cover**

```
<Image style={styles.image} resizeMode="cover" source {require('../assets/img/leong.png')} />
```